# How to reset Combo when SWT.READ_ONLY

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am using the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo` class and I am doing the following

```
Combo myCombo = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);
myCombo.add("1");
myCombo.add("2");

//later on
myCombo.setText(""); //will not work because READ_ONLY
```

The user will choose an element of the combo, and I am providing a reset button where I want the value to be set to null. However, according to the javadoc, the setText method is ignored when the receiver is `READ_ONLY`. I like the `Combo` being read only because I only want the user to select what I provide.. But I want to set the value back to null or "" if possible. Can I do this with a the read only receiver? Or what is another good way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `combo.deselectAll()` to reset the selection.

Alternatively you could use:

```
combo.deselect(combo.getSelectionIndex());
```

In both cases `getSelectionIndex()` will return -1 afterwards.

These methods appear as if the Combo supports multi-selection, which it doesn't. However strange they may appear, they do reset the selection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use ComboViewer

```
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    input.add("1");
    input.add("2");
    combo = new ComboViewer(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    combo.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
    combo.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    combo.setInput(input);
```

And to clear it

```
combo.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
```

Regards